# How to see how much data (in Mo for download/upload) was sent through my Tor usage?

Tags: configuration

How to see how much data (in Mo for download/upload) was sent through my Tor usage? I know that tor.exe in windows says how much data was sent if the connection is re-established, but does it store it somewhere? And I don't know how to look up this in Linux (which I'm using right now).

Answer (score 1):

This is already a built in feature in the [anonymizing relay monitor (Arm)](https://www.atagar.com/arm/) which provides real time statistics for:

1. bandwidth (upload/download), cpu and memory usage
2. relay's current configuration
3. logged events connection details (ip, hostname, fingerprint, and consensus data)
4. ...etc

[image]

(Picture above for the case of a relay, but it also works for a client)

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved via stem-using script. Tor itself makes some runtime data, but does not have a built-in extensive statistics module. You can regulary poll a Tor instance and collect data from running Tor instance and summarize it yourself

Answer (score 0):

The [control port](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort) provides two bits of information [`traffic/read`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=13196900102ff5fb28aa4a5458a53a04971b0adf#n665) and [`traffic/written`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=13196900102ff5fb28aa4a5458a53a04971b0adf#n667) which can be queried by the [`GETINFO`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt?id=13196900102ff5fb28aa4a5458a53a04971b0adf#n484) command.

This will provide the traffic read and written by the Tor daemon since it was last launched.

The [`stem`](https://stem.torproject.org/) library provides a simple interface to the control port illustrated in this example code to fetch these two values, from [this tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html):

```
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()  # provide the password here if you set one

  bytes_read = controller.get_info("traffic/read")
  bytes_written = controller.get_info("traffic/written")

  print("My Tor relay has read %s bytes and written %s." % (bytes_read, bytes_written))
```

While it explicitly states relay, which is it's example use case, this also applies to clients. The above script assumes that Tor is running a control port on 9051/tcp on localhost.